# How Can I read property 'get_tabs' of null in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using ajaxtoolkit controller tab container and I want to enable or disable tabs on certain conditions.For that I have tried following both.

It throws an error as:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_tabs' of null"
>           How I can Enable or disable tabs in jquery or javascript.

Code:

```
$find(ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer_Vendor).get_tabs()[2].set_enabled(false); 

var tab = $find('<%=TabContainer_Vendor.ClientID%>');
tab.get_tabs()[2].set_enabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `tab` is `null`. Therefore it is not a Object, and so it does not have any functions or attributes.

```
var tab = $find('<%=TabContainer_Vendor.ClientID%>');
```

Is not finding the object you wanted and returned null.

Comment: Yes,It is getting null.So I need solution for it.

Comment: explain what exactly you are trying to do with this find

Comment: On webform there are 4 tabs.Onpageload event first tab will be enabled and other three will be disabled.after entering some data on first tab and clicking on next button 2nd tab will be enabled and other three i.e 1st,3rd and 4th will be disabled.and so on.....

Comment: I have no further idea what you are talking about, improve your question